# Is it possible to have multiple timezones in bigquery output?

Tags: time, google-bigquery, timezone

I have an app that is used worldwide and I would like to be able to see the time of day the users are using the app in their timezone, currently I get the time in the default UTC for every user.

I know it is possible to change the default timezone I report in to another, but I haven't been able to find anything for changing it to multiple timezones.

Is this possible? If so any help/ any helpful documents I could follow? I'm using SQL in bigquery.

Many thanks,

Comment: Do you have a column in the user table to say which user should use which timezone? Adding some sample data should be even better.

Comment: Based on the limited info, you may be able to use https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#string function to specify timezone for each user if you have such info.

Comment: Yeah that is my issue that I didn't know I could solve. In the dataset there isn't a timezone  for each entry, just the standard timestamp we get from bigquery. I was wondering if there was a way to determine a user timezones as I have geo data but I do not think this is best practice/ correct way to go about it? But it may be the quickest for me to do this - sigh.

I might have answered my own question for the time being - need to ask the user for their timezone i.e. add it in as dimension I need. Then from there onwards I will have to convert.